# Take certain value in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame and would like to take a certain value from a cell if another is in a dataframe.

I tried the apply function.

```
n <- c(2, 3, 0 ,1) 
s <- c(0, 1, 1, 2) 
b <- c("THIS", "FALSE", "NOT", "THIS") 
df <- data.frame(n, s, b)

df <- sapply(df$Vals, FUN=function(x){ if(b[x]=="THIS") ? n[x] : s[x] } )
```

My logic is:

```
if(b at position x is equal to "This") {
   add n[x] to the column df$Vals
} else {
   add s[x] to the column df$Vals
}
```

Whereas `x` is a single row.

Any recommendation what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
df$Vals = with(df, ifelse(b=="THIS", n, s))
```

Or giving direct the resulting `data.frame`:

```
transform(df, Vals=with(df, ifelse(b=="THIS", n, s)))

#  n s     b Vals
#1 2 0  THIS    2
#2 3 1 FALSE    1
#3 0 1   NOT    1
#4 1 2  THIS    1
```

With your additional conditions:

```
func=Vectorize(function(b, s, n){if(b=='THIS') return(n);if(b==F) return(n+s);s})
df$Vals = with(df, func(b,s,n))
```

Comment: What would I do if have more conditions than this one. like to `if () elseif() else`?

Comment: What are the other conditions? It was not that was asked in the question ;)

Comment: Yep, I didn`t asked for them. However, I just want to learn how I could do it in the future. Any recommendation how I could implement that?

Comment: Again, the most important question is: what are the conditions? I can't guess what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use the `row/column` indexing

```
df$Vals <- df[1:2][cbind(1:nrow(df),(df$b!='THIS')+1)]
df
#  n s     b Vals
#1 2 0  THIS    2
#2 3 1 FALSE    1
#3 0 1   NOT    1
#4 1 2  THIS    1
```